# What is this ruby/rails syntax that looks like a method invocation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know I'm missing something simple here but, the rails guide shows the following example config that can appear in session_store.rb:

```
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session', domain: ".example.com"
```

which looks like an invocation of a method: session_store with args.  However session_store here seems to actually be an instance of `ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore`.

So, what is actually going on here?

Comment: It _is_ a method invocation and `ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore` is the method's return value.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't seem to find this method documented on Rails::Application::Configuration or its parents.  Should it be?  I tried `Rails.application.config.session_store.source_location` to try to determine where it is defined.

Comment: Try `Rails.application.config.method(:session_store).source_location`, it should point to [.../gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:163](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L163)

Comment: Remember that `Rails.application.config.session_store` already invokes the method. It doesn't return a `Method` instance. If you have a function in JavaScript `foo = function() {}`, then `foo` will return that function and `foo()` will call it. In Ruby however, the parentheses are optional. Both, `foo` and `foo()` are equivalent, they call the method `foo`.

Comment: You have cleared up my misunderstanding.  If you'd like to post something as an answer I will mark it accepted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing

```
Rails.application.config.session_store
#=> ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore
```

you are *invoking* the `session_store` method. `ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore` is the method's *return value*, not the method itself. And since `ActiveRecordStore` is a class, it doesn't respond to `source_location`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store.source_location
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `source_location' for ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore:Class
```

In JavaScript (and other languages), a function can be referenced via its name and called by appending parentheses:

```js
function foo() {
  return 123;
}

foo           // function() { return 123; }
typeof foo    // "function"

foo()         // 123
typeof foo()  // "number"
```

In Ruby however, the parentheses are optional when calling a method, both `foo` and `foo()` call the method:

```
def foo
  123
end

foo           #=> 123
foo.class     #=> "fixnum"

foo()         #=> 123
foo().class   #=> "fixnum"
```

To obtain a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Method.html) object for a given method name, you have to call the [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-method) method on its receiver:

```
method(:foo) #=> #<Method: Object#foo>
```

In your case:

```
Rails.application.config.method(:session_store)
#=> #<Method: Rails::Application::Configuration#session_store>

Rails.application.config.method(:session_store).source_location
#=> [".../gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb", 163]
```

Here's the source code: [railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:163](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L163)